# Sort or scope by custom method in rails - Is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I was wondering, let's say I have two models, discussions and post. Posts belong to discussions. I have a custom action in a Discussion model that acts to check the latest activity on an object by checking the creation date of its newest post. ie

```
 def latest activity
     self.posts.last.created_at || self.created_at
 end
```

Can i write a scope that orders the model's objects by this method rather than, say, a column in the Discussion model?

```
 scope :latest_activity, #what to put here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there a reason why you don't want to alter the parent? Rails have a built-in method called touch for this exact thing. For example: belongs_to :discussion, :touch => :last_reply_at will make it so whenever a reply is changed(created/updated) the parent will have that field updated with Time.now timestamp. One benefit of this would be the ability to not query the children every time you want to see which discussion has the last reply.

Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

**EDIT**

Another way to do this would be to add a filter, for instance after_create on the post update a field with the current time on the discussion model.

Comment: the reason why I don't alter the parent is simply that I feel it would be redundant add that field to the parent, and then also update with each post. is this misguided?

Comment: i can see how this would be an alternative solution. But, as per the question, is there a way to scope without recording a field in the parent (and scope through a method)?

Comment: Try this: scope :latest_activity, includes(:posts).order("posts.created_at DESC")

Comment: excellent! If you put that line into your answer, I will attribute the answer as your response. (You can leave the rest of the answer in too, it is all relevant)

Comment: .. actually, just a sec, got to check some things with this.

Comment: yeah - this, and/or joins(:posts) may be the direction to go in.. but only if I could sort by the last post only, and add a condition to use the discussion created_at if there are no posts. But I don't know if that is possible